# How to get array info from column in Spring Boot JPA (exception Dialect mapping for JDBC type Error)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem to get `{"role1","role2","role3"}` from roles column.

Here is the entity shown below

```
@Entity
public class User {
    //...

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
    @Type(type = "com.baeldung.hibernate.arraymapping.CustomStringArrayType")
    private String[] roles;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Here is the JPARepository shown below

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT unnest(u.roles)::text FROM User u", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findDistinctRoles();
}
```

I got nested exception Dialect mapping for JDBC type?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Postgree JDBC/Database? this syntax is compatible with Postgree Database.
If yes, check the dialect in configuration file, it should be: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect. and if it's ok, try to execute the sql query directly in your database and check if it will be executed properly.

Comment: How can I do through unnest in the query?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are storing roles as "," separated string Array.

This is what I have in the User entity.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
private String[] roles;
```

In pgAdmin, I can see my ***roles*** column being stored like

```
{ADMIN,CUSTOMER}
{ADMIN,USER}
{ADMIN,USER}
```

Create the following in the UserRepository and it will get you the list of distinct roles.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT STRING_TO_TABLE(BTRIM(CAST(roles AS text), '{}'), ',') from user", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findDistinctRoles();
```

Here we are casting the roles column as text, removing the "{}" from there, and then getting the distinct values from the list of roles.

To do this using **`unnest`**, you can do the following.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT unnest(roles) from employee", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findDistinctRoles();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How can I do through unnest in the query?

Comment: @jacksondel just updated the answer to use unnest.